# iOS text-to-speech in background

Tags: ios, audio, text-to-speech, background-process

I am having an intermittent (aargh!) problem playing Text-to-Speech in the background, triggered from Apple Watch. I have properly set up the background mode, the AVSession category, and the WatchKitExtensionRequest handler. (See below.) I had this working before, and can't figure out what changed. (Could it be iOS 9 has issues? "Before" means, among other things, iOS 8.)

The problem is this: when the app gets the request from the Watch and the app is either in the background or the phone is sleeping (locked), the speech *sometimes* plays right away, and *other times* doesn't play until the app is brought to the foreground. The OS seems to be sometimes queuing the audio, and sometimes not. I can't find any common thread between success and failure cases. I can verify with logging that the call to speakUtterance() *is* being made in *all* situations. But its behavior varies, apparently randomly. The only clue is that it *might* be the case that the longer the app is in the background, the less likely it is to speak right away.

This is making me pull my hair out. Suggestions welcome.

### In info.plist:

Required background modes: App plays audio or streams audio/video using AirPlay

### In AppDelegate.application:didFinishLaunching:withOptions():

```
do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(
        AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, 
        withOptions:.DuckOthers
    )
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
} catch let error as NSError {
    // etc...
}
```

### In AppDelegate.application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest...():

```
var bgTaskId:UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = 0
bgTaskId = application.beginBackgroundTaskWithName(
    "Prose WKE handler",
    expirationHandler: {
        application.endBackgroundTask(bgTaskId)
    }
)
//... Post notification to call Text-to-Speech
application.endBackgroundTask(bgTaskId)
```

Comment: I have the same problem though initiated with push notifications. But I will try your word-around for sure :)

Comment: Good luck! I have not recently checked to see if this is no longer needed. I suspect it is an Apple bug. Let me know how it works for you.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a workaround: play a second snippet of sound (I used a half-second of silence), using AVAudioPlayer, right after the call to speakUtterance(), This seems to "jog the pipeline".

Comment: Hi Andrew - your work-around has worked successfully during the weekend - thanks :D I have filed a bug-report to Apple about it.